# How to play against the Noteboom variation?

Tags: opening, 1.d4, semi-slav

In online games I sometimes have this happen:

```
[fen ""]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 c6 3.Nf3 e6 4.Nc3 dxc4
```

and Black plays the famous "Noteboom variation".  I checked my database and I have in fact lost every single game as White where this variation happened. Usually Black just arranges his pieces nicely and pushes the a-pawn and b-pawn and I lose material due to pieces getting trapped in the corner, or having to give up pieces to stop the pawns promoting.

What is a promising way to meet this system for White?

Note: Of course, I could avoid the line with 4.e3 going into a normal Meran. But I often play quickly the first few moves of an internet game and carelessly make a natural developing move with the knight. It would be good to know how to recover from this.

Comment: `4. Nc3` is perhaps the main move, and you shouldn't give it a dubious mark.

Comment: CCSCSL have a video about this opening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFI0nON4QDg

Answer (score 1):

In this variation, black is behind development after

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[WhiteELO "?"]
[BlackELO "?"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pp3ppp/2p1p3/8/2pP4/2N2N2/PP2PPPP/R1BQKB1R w KQkq - 0 1"]


1. Bf4 Bb4 2. e3 Bxc3+ 3. bxc3 b5 4. a4 Nf6 5. axb5 cxb5 6. Rb1
```

White has more center control, and black will probably have a backward pawn if he tries to hang onto c4.

Another variation I like is

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "????.??.??"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "*"]
[WhiteELO "?"]
[BlackELO "?"]
[SetUp "1"]
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pp3ppp/2p1p3/8/2pP4/2N2N2/PP2PPPP/R1BQKB1R w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. e3 b5 2. b3 Bb4 3. Bb2 cxb3 4. Qxb3 Bxc3 5. Qxc3 Nf6 6. Bd3
```

which creates lots of attacking chances for white.

Comment: To be totally honest, in your first variation I'd prefer Black. E.g. `6. ... Qa5 7. Qc2 Nd5` and unless I am missing something obvious White has serious problems with `c3` pawn.

Comment: I would also say that in both suggestions black can play for an advantage. After 5.Bf4, black seems to be more than ok after 5....Nf6 or 5....b5. And after 5.e3 b5 6.b3, black can play 6....b4 and 7....c3.

Comment: I think Black is not forced to take on c3 in your first line, it seems better to leave it there and threaten Nf6-d5 which bites without the White possibility of Bd2.

Comment: I will give these lines a deeper thought, but I think I have analyzed Nf6 and Qa4 and saw that there are nice counterplays for white such as `5. Bf4 Nf6 6. e4 b5 7. e5` or `6. ... Qa5 7. Bd6 Qxc3+ 8. Ke2` and `9. Bc4` black's position is cramped.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the sharp positions where black has the connected passed a- and b-pawns, white can switch to systems with g3. This is what white opted for in [Nakamura-Ivanchuk](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1653869) and [Giri-Caruana](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1705524).

In the first game, Nakamura played 5.g3. If black replies with 5....Nf6, then the game transposes to a theoretical line that arises after 1.d4 d5 2.c4 c6 3.Nf3 Nf6 4.Nc3 e6 5.g3 dxc4.
Instead, Ivanchuk tried to postpone Nf6 and played 5....b5 6.Bg2 Bb7 7.Ne5 Qc8. However, it seems that Nakamura was able to develop a dangerous initiative.

In the second game, Giri first played 5.a4 and after 5....Bb4, he went for 6.g3, probably hoping for a good version of the 5.g3 variation.

```
      [FEN ""]
      [StartPly "8"]

      1.d4 d5 2.c4 c6 3.Nf3 e6 (3...Nf6 4.Nc3 e6 5.g3 dxc4) 4.Nc3 dxc4 5.a4 (5.g3 Nf6) Bb4 6.g3
```

Comment: In the Nakamura game, 13.Rd1 seems extremely dangerous to Black. I guess Black will be forced to return the pawn earlier to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your playing style, answering this question is difficult.

As a 2000 who plays this defense, the line I have the most trouble with is the Nd2 line.

1 d4 d5 2 c4 e6 3 Nc3 c6 4 Nf3 dxc4 5 a4 Bb4 6 e3 b5 7, Bd2 a5 8 axb5 Bxc3 
9 Bc3 cxb5 10 b3 Bb7 11 bxc4 b4 12 Bb2 Nf6 13 Bd3 Nbbd7 14 o-o o-o 15 Nd2 (or Bc2 followed by Nd3.) ["The Triangle System" by Sherbakov is a good reference book.]

A good plan would be to switch to the Catalan after Black weakens the long diagonal.

Comment: I think you mean `a5` on move 7.

Comment: Yes, and I meant that to be move 7 not 1 again.